# Set CSS style on selected text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a function that changes CSS styles when you select it from a dropdown. I'm using the `switch` function for the different CSS styles for the different cases. How do I add styling to whatever element is selected?

```
onClick : function( value ){                           
              switch (value) {
                  case "remove_border": remove_border(editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()); break;
              }                    
          }


function remove_border(selection) {    
    /* what must I put in here to make this function work?  */
    alert(selection);
}
```

Comment: This is missing information, I cannot give you a straight answer... However, going off what you've written above: jQuery: `$('mySelector').css("border", "none");` where `mySelector` is how you are getting the specified element (i.e. `#myId`, `.myClass` `div` [or other elements]). JavaScript: `document.getElementById("myId").style.border = "none";` assuming you're getting the element by its id (`myId`). If using JavaScript to get element by class name use `getElementsByClassName()` method, and if getting element by tag name use `getElementsByTagName()` method

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to your elements and do a getElementById(x);

If I'm misunderstanding, you might want to provide a jsfiddle so we can see what you're trying to do.